# Read multiple CSV file and write them to new CSV file php

Tags: php

I have multiple `.csv` file with the same column. I wanna merge them to a new `.csv` file. But i get empty file `.csv`

For example, i have three files:

CSV 1:

```
ID,name,age
1,Andy,18
2,Mary,19
3,Buddy,19
...
```

CSV 2:

```
ID,name,age
5,Andy,18
6,Cindy,20
...
```

CSV 3:

```
ID,name,age
9,Mody,18
10,Trudy,20
15,Windy,20
17,Somebody,22
...
```

There is result i want:

```
ID,name,age
1,Andy,18
2,Mary,19
3,Buddy,19
5,Andy,18
6,Cindy,20
9,Mody,18
10,Trudy,20
15,Windy,20
17,Somebody,22
```

I try with my code but it give me empty file:

```
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",");
fclose($handle);
$name = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'pathfile.csv';
$fopen = fopen($name, 'a');
fputcsv($fopen,$data,',','');
fclose($fopen);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
function joinFiles(array $files, $result) {
if(!is_array($files)) {
    throw new Exception('`$files` must be an array');
}

$wH = fopen($result, "w+");

foreach($files as $file) {
    $fh = fopen($file, "r");
    while(!feof($fh)) {
        fwrite($wH, fgets($fh));
    }
    fclose($fh);
    unset($fh);
    fwrite($wH, "\n"); //usually last line doesn't have a newline
}
fclose($wH);
unset($wH);
}?>
```

USAGE:

```
<?php
joinFiles(array('join1.csv', 'join2.csv'), 'join3.csv');?>
```

After combining you can easily sort